# Copying bin files to docker container leads to error

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to setup a `docker-compose` system where I'd like to copy dev tools to `/usr/local/bin/` on startup.

Thats my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: docker/container/nginx
    ports:
      - 4000:80
    volumes: &m2volume
      - ./src:/var/www/html/
      - ./docker/data/bin/:/usr/local/bin/
      - ~/.composer:/var/www/.composer
    networks: &m2network
      - www
    links:
      - "php"
      - "mariadb:mysql"
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb
    ports:
      - 8001:3306
    networks: *m2network
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: magento2
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db
      MYSQL_USER: magento2
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: magento2
    volumes:
      - ./docker/container/db/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
      - ./docker/container/db/conf.d:/etc/mysql/conf.d
      - ./docker/data/mariadb:/var/lib/mysql

  php:
    build: docker/container/fpm
    volumes: *m2volume
    networks: *m2network

networks:
  www:
```

if I leave `- ./docker/data/bin/:/usr/local/bin/` in it, I get an error:

```
ERROR: for m2_php_1  Cannot start service php: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "exec: \"docker-php-entrypoint\": executable file not found in $PATH"
Starting m2_mariadb_1 ... done

ERROR: for php  Cannot start service php: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "exec: \"docker-php-entrypoint\": executable file not found in $PATH"
```

If I uncomment it, all works fine.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: if you uncomment it it would be the same as leaving it. In other words, does commenting it out work or not?

Comment: Without `#` I'm getting the error @omu_negru

Answer (score 0):

If i understand this correctly, and mapping the volume `./docker/data/bin/:/usr/local/bin/` is causing an exception, then that's probably because of the [entrypoint](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) defined in the mariadb image.

More to the point, you're overwriting the `/usr/local/bin` container folder, which probably contains an executable used in the entrypoint. When that disappears, you get an error.

Comment: To add to this answer, OP may mount individual files to that folder to avoid replacing the default contents in the folder.